# Automatic label text update in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

If I set the value of a string in one form and then display in label on another form by clicking a "update" button on the second form. This part works.

I would like to know how I can make the label update it's text value after the first form closes.

If I try doing with:

public static void Subject_select()
        {

```
    L_Subject.Text = Global.Subject;

    }
```

And then running this with:

```
    msinForm.Subject_select();
```

Then it throws the error:
An object reference is required for the non-static field,method, or property 'app1.mainForm.L_Subject'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose  better approch is create [Global event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) and fire it when in a first form text was changed and than in second form subscribe to an event and change text in event handler.

Check about global events [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475723/writing-a-global-custom-event-in-c). If you will go through static events beware of memory leaks.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to C# would be able to give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use `FormClosed` event of second form. subscribe to it from the first form. In event handler you should update your label